# C# ToList or list add make wrong result

Tags: c#, list

```
var su = SysallocunitsRow<sysallocunit>(myreader);

List<sysallocunit> sul= new List<sysallocunit>();

foreach( var s in su)
{
    logger.Info("su auid is  " + s.auid);
    sul.Add(s);
}

foreach (var a in sul)
{
    logger.Info("sul unit is  " + a.auid);
}
```

The result :

````
```
.........................
su auid is  72057594048675840
su auid is  72057594049265664
su auid is  72057594049331200
su auid is  72057594049462272
su auid is  72057594049527808
su auid is  72057594049658880

sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
sul unit is  72057594049658880
```
````

I want to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a list, but `.ToList()` or `List.Add()` cause the list duplicate the last one, and have wrong result.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Hi Parnassus, what are you trying to acheive your intentions behind your code is not clear, can you clarify ?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Please try `var su = SysallocunitsRow<sysallocunit>(myreader).ToList();` and my assumption would be now both lists will have all duplicates. The problem seems to be that this `SysallocunitsRow` is returning the same object with different values each iteration. The first time you iterate you use the values for your console write, but you store a reference so the 2nd list ends up with all duplicates

Comment: Hi Parnassus, let me know if the solution below was able to answer your question, if yes, please click on the green tickbox to accept as answer, that way it would benefit others in the community

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding s into sul, create a new object of sysallocunit and add it. 
Changing your first foreach as below should resolve the issue of duplicate values.

```
foreach( var s in su)
{
    logger.Info("su auid is  " + s.auid);
    sul.Add(new sysallocunit(){ auid = s.auid });
}
```